# Show GROUP members' COUNT w/o actually GROUPing

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I want to show a user's new messages since his last online activity. This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    from_user_id, 
    to_user_id, 
    from_user_id + to_user_id AS combined_key, 
    chat_date, 
    last_activity, 
    message, 
    username, 
    city
FROM chat AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.from_user_id = u.id)
WHERE (from_user_id = '4' OR to_user_id = '4') AND chat_date > '2014-06-19 00:00:00.0'
ORDER BY combined_key ASC, chat_date ASC
```

...which produces the following result:
[image]

Now I would like to add a column which shows in each row the number of messages with the same *combined_key*, so this subtotal column would e.g. in the first three rows show *3* (because there are 3 messages with *combined_key '9'*).

So something like

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS subtotal, 
    from_user_id, 
    to_user_id, 
    from_user_id + to_user_id AS combined_key, 
    chat_date, 
    last_activity, 
    message, 
    username, 
    city
FROM chat AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.from_user_id = u.id)
WHERE (from_user_id = '4' OR to_user_id = '4') AND chat_date > '2014-06-19 00:00:00.0'
GROUP BY combined_key
```

...but without actually grouping and thus eliminating some rows:
[image]

Comment: what if three or more share the same combined_key ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a subselect to your select statement. In sql, you can add a subselect anywhere. Instead of comparing information or creating a table in the subselect, we are going to return data. You may need to edit this subselect in order to use your specifications (for instance, you may want to specify the chat date like in your where clause). Also, depending on how your join affects the returned rows, you may need to include the join in the subselect as well. You'll have to try a few things out and see! Using your original query:

```
SELECT (Select count(1)
          from chat c2
          where c2.combined_key = c.combined_key
          Group by c2.combined_key) as subtotal,
      from_user_id,
      to_user_id,
      from_user_id + to_user_id AS combined_key,
      chat_date,
      last_activity,
      message,
      username,
      city
 FROM chat AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.from_user_id = u.id)
 WHERE (from_user_id = '4' OR to_user_id = '4') AND chat_date > '2014-06-19 00:00:00.0'
 ORDER BY combined_key ASC, chat_date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, but this query produces _Error code 1054, SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'c2.combined_key' in 'where clause'_ and I can't get it to work...

Comment: Is there a syntax error? I'm not getting any issues. I created a very bare bones fiddle example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21758/5

Comment: Thank you, Jenn, I've meanwhile solved it in a similar way (see my answer)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thanks for your contributions, I finally did it:

```
SELECT from_user_id, 
to_user_id, 
from_user_id + to_user_id AS combined_key,
(
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
  FROM chat AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.from_user_id = u.id)
  WHERE (from_user_id = '4' OR to_user_id = '4') AND chat_date > '2014-06-19 00:00:00.0' AND (from_user_id + to_user_id) = combined_key
  ) AS subtotal,

chat_date, 
last_activity, 
message, 
username, 
city
FROM chat AS c JOIN users AS u ON (c.from_user_id = u.id)
WHERE (from_user_id = '4' OR to_user_id = '4')
ORDER BY combined_key ASC, chat_date ASC
```

[image]